# How to use “how could” to express

Tags: sentence-meaning

I want to say, **“No one can refuse this pretty face.”**

Can I use, **“How could someone refuse this pretty face?”** as well?

Is it the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

It could mean the same thing, if you are asking it as a **rhetorical question** (that is, a question that is not meant to be answered, but it is assumed that the answer is evident and obvious). As [one website](https://literarydevices.net/rhetorical-question/) says:

> A rhetorical question is asked just for effect, or to lay emphasis on some point being discussed, when no real answer is expected. A rhetorical question may have an obvious answer, but the questioner asks it to lay emphasis to the point. In literature, a rhetorical question is self-evident, and used for style. Broadly speaking, a rhetorical question is asked when the questioner knows the answer already, or an answer is not actually demanded [or] expected.

However, if the question is not interpreted as rhetorical, but as a request for information, then the question would not longer be synonymous with the original assertion.